# How do I put labels on nodes in a tree diagram?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees

I need to create a specific diagram in my document, but I can't manage to do it. I have most of it, but I can't seem to get a child below the node if I already have another child on the right (blue ellipses). And then, how to get these children below all on the same level? And I would also like to have just 1 arrow, while the other children are linked only by a line.

[image]

This is what I have so far :

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

 \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\A}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\B}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}\xspace}
\newcommand\pa[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm,level distance=4.5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=4cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=3.5cm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=2.5cm},
level 5/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=2.5cm},
edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=blue!40!black!60,
    shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
kant/.style={text width=2cm, text centered, sloped},
every node/.style={text ragged, inner sep=2mm},
punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, shade, top color=white,
bottom color=blue!50!black!20, draw=blue!40!black!60, very
thick }
]

\node[punkt, text width=5.5em] {*/aper-i-/}
%Lower part lv1
child {
    node[punkt, text width=6em] {\hspace{10pt}*/a'pert-/}
     %child 2
    child {
        node [punkt]{
            \textbf{*/apert-/}
        }
        child {
        node [punkt]{
            \textbf{*/-ur-/}
        }
        child {
        node [punkt]{
            \textbf{*/-a/}
        }}}}
        edge from parent{
            node[kant, below] {thème 1}}
}
child {
    node[punkt] [text ragged] {
        \textbf{*/'aperu-/}
    }
    edge from parent
        node[kant, below, pos=.6] {thème 2}
}
%Upper part, lv1
child {
    node[punkt, text width=6em] {\hspace{10pt}*/aper-/}
        edge from parent{
            node[kant, below] {thème 1}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). This isn't a "Please do my work for me" site! What do you have so far? Try to create ... . To start maybe [Trees examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) could help.

Comment: So what is the actual question?  How to put the labels for the levels in the tree?  (The ones you have in blue ellipses...)

Comment: Exactly. I don't know how to put 1 child below if I already have another child on the right.

Comment: OT:  please don't use `minimal` class - `standalone` class is better for this sort of example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:**

- your "tree" is more easy draw with help of `matrix`
- multi line nodes had to be explicit written as node with names
- fill color can be determined localy

the first try:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, quotes, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {font=\ttfamily, align=left, inner sep=2mm},
     punkt/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners,
            draw=blue!40!black!60, very thick,
            top color=white, bottom color=blue!50!black!20,
            %                shade,
                    },
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto=left, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                                   anchor=south, sloped},
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
%             nodes in empty cells,
             nodes={punkt},
             column sep=12mm, row sep=6mm,
             column 1/.style = {column sep=33mm},
             row 4/.style = {nodes={ellipse, fill=blue!30,
                             anchor=north, inner xsep=0mm}}]
{
*/a'pert-/  & */apert-/     &               &           &               \\
            & */'aperu-/    &               &           &               \\
            & */'aper-/     & */'aper-i-/   & */-ur-/   & */-a/         \\
base        & themes        & \node{radical selectionne\\
                              parmi les different\\
                              themes};
                                            & norphene suffixal
                                                        & \node{morphene flexionnel\\
                                                          marquant la categorie\\
                                                          gramaticale};   \\
};
\draw   (m-1-1)  to ["thème 1"]     (m-1-2)
        (m-1-1)  to ["thème 2"]     (m-2-2)
        (m-1-1)  to ["thème 1"]     (m-3-2);
\draw   (m-3-2) -- (m-3-3)
        (m-3-3) -- (m-3-4)
        (m-3-4) -- (m-3-5);
\draw   (m-1-1) -- (m-4-1)
        (m-3-2) -- (m-4-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the second try:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, quotes, shapes}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
punkt/.style = {top color=white, bottom color=blue!50!black!20},
pnktr/.style = {fill=red!20},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=left, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                            anchor=south, sloped},
                    ]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
             nodes={rectangle, rounded corners,
                    draw=blue!40!black!60, very thick,
                    font=\ttfamily, align=left, inner sep=2mm,
                    },
             column sep=6mm, row sep=8mm,
             column 1/.style = {column sep=33mm},
             row 4/.style = {nodes={ellipse, draw=blue!40!black!60, very thick,
                                    fill=cyan!20, anchor=north, inner xsep=0mm}}
             ]
{
|[punkt]| */a'pert-/  
    & |[punkt]| */apert-/   &   &   &               \\
    & |[punkt]| */'aperu-/  &   &   &               \\
    & |[punkt]| */'aper-/   
        & |[pnktr]| */'aper-i-/ 
                            & |[pnktr]| */-ur-/ 
                                & |[pnktr]| */-a/   \\
base        
    & themes                
        & \node (m-4-3)
          {radical selectionne\\
          parmi les different\\
          themes};          & morphene suffixal
                                & \node (m-4-5)
                                  {morphene flexionnel\\
                                  marquant la categorie\\
                                  gramaticale};   \\
};
\draw   (m-1-1)  edge ["thème 1"]     (m-1-2)
        (m-1-1)  edge ["thème 2"]     (m-2-2)
        (m-1-1)  edge ["thème 1"]     (m-3-2);
\draw   (m-3-2) -- (m-3-3)
        (m-3-3) -- (m-3-4)
        (m-3-4) -- (m-3-5);
\draw   (m-1-1) -- (m-4-1)
        (m-3-2) -- (m-4-2)
        (m-3-3) -- (m-4-3)
        (m-3-4) -- (m-4-4)
        (m-3-5) -- (m-4-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the `positioning` library.  I'm no Tikz expert but this might give you a starting point.  If you want the labels decorated, then you can add a style like any other node.   And you will want to fix the horizontal spacing of your nodes to make room for the labels.

[image]

Note: I compiled this with `xelatex` for the unicode accented characters.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\A}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\B}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}\xspace}
\newcommand\pa[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm,level distance=4.5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=4cm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=3.5cm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=2.5cm},
level 5/.style={sibling distance=2cm, level distance=2.5cm},
edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=blue!40!black!60,
    shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
kant/.style={text width=2cm, text centered, sloped},
every node/.style={text ragged, inner sep=2mm},
punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, shade, top color=white,
bottom color=blue!50!black!20, draw=blue!40!black!60, very
thick }
]

    \node[punkt, text width=5.5em] (T1) {*/aper-i-/}
%Lower part lv1
child {
    node[punkt, text width=6em] (T2) {\hspace{10pt}*/a'pert-/}
     %child 2
    child {
        node [punkt] (T3) {
            \textbf{*/apert-/}
        }
        child {
            node [punkt] (T4) {
            \textbf{*/-ur-/}
        }
        child {
            node [punkt] (T5) {
            \textbf{*/-a/}
        }}}}
        edge from parent{
            node[kant, below] {thème 1}}
}
child {
    node[punkt] [text ragged] {
        \textbf{*/'aperu-/}
    }
    edge from parent
        node[kant, below, pos=.6] {thème 2}
}
%Upper part, lv1
child {
    node[punkt, text width=6em] {\hspace{10pt}*/aper-/}
        edge from parent{
            node[kant, below] {thème 1}}
};

    \node[below = 4.5cm of T1] {Base};
    \node[below =of T2] {Thèmes};
    \node[below =of T3, text width=3cm] {Radical selectionné parmi les autres thèmes};
    \node[below =of T4, text width=3cm] {Morphème suffixal};
    \node[below =of T5, text width=3cm] {Morphème flexionnel marquant la whatever};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I added:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

and then named the relevant nodes like this:

```
\node[punkt, text width=5.5em] (T1) {*/aper-i-/}
```

The name is the bit in (parentheses).

Then I can define another node like this:

```
\node[below = 4.5cm of T1] {Base};
```